# Cannot click on menu bar, joomla mobile site

Tags: joomla-3.x, responsive-web-design

[This](http://www.loirevalleywineries.com/) is the site, if we drag it through the chrome or ff its menu works fine in all the resolutions, but if we open this on any mobile, we cannot click on top menu bar, why is that ?
and how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In file `/templates/lvwineries/css/style.css`
on line 248 in selector `#bottom2` add attribute `z-index: -1;` like this:

> #bottom2 {
>    min-height: 400px;
>    position: relative;
>    z-index: -1;
>   }

on line 1200 in selector `#header_right` add attribute `z-index:1;` like this:

> #header_right {
>       height: 99px;
>       z-index:1;
>   }

on line 1204 in selector `.menu_principal` add attribute `z-index:2:` like this:

> .menu_principal {
>       width: 481px;
>       z-index: 2;
>   }

That should make menu links clickable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, but can you explain what was wrong with it and what we did in order to fix it, i am new to front end.

Comment: You're welcome. Overlapping and wrong-sized divs #bottom2 and #header_right have caused it. This template looks to me as desktop-only type, and just lightly re-worked recently to fit mobile devices. If this was mobile-first type, it would have bootstrap.css, hamburger menu or off-canvas menu, etc...